# jps command for Hadoop processes

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, terminal

there. I have hadoop 2.4.1 running on ubuntu. Executing jps command, I am getting this output:

```
7394 DataNode
3794 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
8053 NodeManager
7190 NameNode
7638 SecondaryNameNode
7868 ResourceManager
8364 Jps
```

is it normal to get "3794 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar" along with the output of jps?

I am asking because didn't get it before. Suddenly, it started to give this result with jps.

Comment: I think I figured this out.I think it's just because Eclipse is running when I execute jps. Because when I close it and run jps, it doesn't give that "3794 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jps` lists all Java processes on your machine. It is not specific to Hadoop.

If you had Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, whatever running on that machine, then you will see those processes

Comment: Thank you. This helps alot =) !

Answer (score 0):

The full form of JPS is Java Virtual Machine Process Status.
JPS command is used to check if a specific daemon is up or not. The command of JPS displays all the processes that are based on Java for a particular user. The command of JPS should run from the root to check all the operating nodes in the host.